# Insert text at the cursor in X11, from within my program

Tags: linux, x11

A program performs a useful computation and inserts the result at the computer user's X11 cursor. How would the program access X11 to insert that text?

*Clarification:*

- That is, if the user's X11 cursor is in a textarea or text editor,
  the result is inserted there.
- This is not a flawed idea because the program
  itself would be triggered by a keyboard binding.

Comment: Not possible in general. One can try `XSendEvent` or `XTestFakeKeyEvent` but neither is guaranteed to work. I have know idea whether PHP has bindings to either one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rely on the use of selections ([see the ICCCM specs here](http://www.x.org/docs/ICCCM/icccm.pdf)). Generally speaking, into an X11 application, the widgets (eg text-boxes, buttons, etc..) must not necessarily be windows (as it happens in Windows), thus they must not necessarily have a Window ID, because GUI toolkits can handle widgets in different ways.